# BeanPropertyRowMapper vs RowMapper

Tags: java, performance, spring-jdbc

I have a table with more than 100 columns. We are using spring jdbc in our application. 
As there were so many columns in the table, I decided to use BeanPropertyRowMapper for fetching the records from DB. This was to avoid writing the hardcoded column and property names in the code which become difficult to manage. 
However, when the application went to performance test, I found that there is significant performance hit due to using BeanPropertyRowMapper. I decide to re-write the code with RowMapper with mapping columns names manually from resultSet to the data object properties. This improved the performance.

My question is, if BeanPropertyRowMapper cannot be used with high number of columns, then how is it helping writing cleaner manageable code. 
Is there any other way using JDBC I can achieve performance as well as manageable code?

Comment: if you are really concerned about the performance issue, you can use queryForRowSet method. but this involves little extra coding to map the result to a domain object. queryForRowSet is much faster.